# Date declaration in datenumber

Tags: babel, datetime

In the following MWE, `\today` prints the date in British format, e.g. 14th January 2013.  However, `\datedate` prints the date as January 28, 2013.  I wonder how the latter can be changed to the former.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datenumber}
\usepackage[british]{babel}

\begin{document}

\today

\setdatetoday
\addtocounter{datenumber}{14}%
\setdatebynumber{\thedatenumber}%
In 14 days is \datedate

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, which worked as expected.  Much appreciated.  By your request, I have accepted Heiko's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Package `datenumber` knows some language options. It does not know `british` but `english`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{datenumber}
\usepackage[british]{babel}

\begin{document}

\today

\setdatetoday
\addtocounter{datenumber}{14}%
\setdatebynumber{\thedatenumber}%
In 14 days is \datedate.

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

You can define your own command with the help of the [`engord`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/engord) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datenumber}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{engord}

\engordraisefalse
\newcommand\mydatedate{%
\engord{dateday}~\datemonthname\ \thedateyear}

\begin{document}

\today

\setdatetoday
\addtocounter{datenumber}{14}%
\setdatebynumber{\thedatenumber}%
In 14 days is \datedate

In 14 days is \mydatedate

\end{document}
```

[image]